# mongo search sub string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello all I am working on some application using MongoDB and I have to find sub string in the collection.

I have a collection Query, as shown below.

```
> db.Query.find();

>{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c9ec8ead38d420d87743b0"), "QueryID" : 1, "QueryString" : "
List my games", "QueryFrequency" : 9, "QueryResultset" : 3 }

>...
```

Now I want to search sub string in the QueryString.
e.g. here "games" in "QueryString" : "List my games"

For this I enabled indexing on QueryString and after running the following command I am getting some results also.

```
> db.Query.runCommand("text" , {search : "games"});
```

"text" is name given to my index.

Now the problem is that I get result only when the word that I am searching has length greater than 3 (i.e. has more than 3 characters)

For my example I get results when I search with word "List" or "games",
But when I use "my" or any other word having less than 4 character gives no result.

Is there any way to solve this or am I missing some settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for this. Your query would be like

```
db.collection.find({"query_string":{$regex: your_regex }})
```

Comment: You can even use regex literals for that: `{$regex: /games/}`.

Comment: Thanks, this is working , But this is a case sensitive search, is there any way to do it to match different case.

Comment: I have used > db.Query.find({"QueryString":{$regex:"list"}}) , so it gives different result for "list" and "List"

Comment: you can specify ignore case in regex, sommething like `/Games/i`

Comment: That worked great, Thanks man. can you tell me how to implement this in C#. Currently I am using `var collection = database.GetCollection("Query").Find(Query.Text("list"));`

Comment: check end of page [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/)

Answer (score 0):

For case in-sensitive search you could use this

```
db.users.find ({ "name" : /my/i } )
```

Where the i stands for insensitive